# Rails 3 - Suggests on a model for Photos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking for suggestions on creating a model/scaffold for Photos

I want a user to be able to create a album that contains 1 or more photos.

Current idea:

```
album
id, name, user_id

photos
id, name, album_id
```

Thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above works fine if you want to constrain each photo to only one album. If a photo can belong to multiple albums you'll have to look into the has_many :through relationship.

[Rails Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: Cool,  a photo only needs to belong to one album. Propably shouldenforce that too